# How can I use executereader for different variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, executescalar, executereader

I use `ExecuteScalar` for single query like this:

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection Connection;
    using (Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=DATABASE:1521/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;Password=PASSWORD;User ID=USERNAME"))
    {
    OleDbCommand Command1, Command2, Command3;

    Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT HOUR FROM Table1 WHERE type='CAR' and name='FERRARI'",", Connection);
    Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT HOUR FROM Table1 WHERE type='CAR' and name='FORD'", Connection);
    Command3 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT HOUR FROM Table1 WHERE type='CAR' and name='OPEL'", Connection);

    Connection.Open();
    var1 = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
    var2 = (int)Command2.ExecuteScalar();
    var3 = (int)Command3.ExecuteScalar();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

It's working fine for me. But 3 (and more for other databases) query waiting so much because of database. How can I select all table (select * from Table1) and after execute commands for every where condition? Can you show me example for this on my sample code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple commands to the database at once (separated by semicolons). You can get each result set using [OleDb.NextResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx). This will cause one back-and-forth to the database, rather than the three you have now.